# How to disable the home key when the menu or Alarm Dialog pop up?

Tags: android

How to disable the home key when the menu or Alarm Dialog pop up?
I know how to disable the home key in the activity. But when the menu or Alarm Dialog pop up, the way is invalid. How to implement this function. Or is there no way to deal with this case?

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you want to disable home button?

Comment: @MuratNafiz This is the customers' requirement in my project. They expect the application will not exit when user presses home key.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable Home Key . for this is the last chance the Android System ESCAPE the application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That is to say, I can't deal with in this case.

Comment: Yes. so punch on the customers's face. :) 有些客户就是乱提需求。不要鸟他们。

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement in my project. Here is my solution:

1) You should have a rooted device.

2) Make sure that your activity is main activity, it should have params like these:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

If you have it, when you tap home button android suggest you other apps except Launcher...

3) Next, since we have rooted device, just find and rename Launcher.apk to LauncerBBB.apk(it can be done programmatically even).

4) That's all. Now only your app is main and it will be shown by Home key tap.

P.S. If you need to have an access to Launcher you can start LauncerBBB activity from secret menu of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This method maybe is good way for rooted device to solve this case. But unfortunately, my project is not run in rooted device.

Comment: You said that "I know how to disable the home key in the activity". But your project is not run on rooted devices.
How did you disable Home button without root?